# How to access directory outside the application using spring mvc and jsp?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

My application is allowed the customer to upload their images. So I am thinking to store those images some where and in my local disk, for instance /home/images/, and save the image path into the database. The problem I have is I am lacking of knowledge how to access the directory outside the application. Thank you in advance.

Comment: new File('/home/images'); you just need to make sure that the user who is running the webserver has permission to access that folder.

Comment: the other way is you can use S3 instance and save the image into it and use the file image url and save it into the database

Comment: @fmodos: I understand what new File('/home/images') will do, but I am not sure how that code will help to display the images in the jsp page?

Comment: http://www.journaldev.com/2573/spring-mvc-file-upload-example-tutorial-single-and-multiple-files You can go through to this tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

To save the files you have to use the java.nio.Files API or any other that allows you to create files. To read the images you can use serving [static content via Spring MVC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html). The configuration in XML looks like that:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/images/**" location="file:/home/images/"/>
```

It makes the application look for the files (and folders) in your `/home/images/` folder for all requests you make for the `/resources/images/**`.

Notice the `file:` prefix. It refers to the absolute path. When you want to set the location of your files relative to the application just leave the prefix out, e.g. `/WEB-INF/images/`.